# How to install Ubuntu on the Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I have read about this on [XDA Developers](http://www.xda-developers.com), the articles were a few months old though.

Is there an official guide from Ubuntu on how to do this?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/run-ubuntu-linux-on-samsung-galaxy-s3/) of any help?

Comment: There is no official guide because it's not an official way to Install Ubuntu.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn’t take the risk of transforming my expensive phone into a brick…

Answer (score 14):

#### Is there a guide to installing Ubuntu on other devices?

The short answer is **no**, there is not. At the moment, the only release available is not for commercial or normal use, and for developers only. It's very unstable and shouldn't be done by those who are not serious about developing with that software and hardware.

#### What are my options?

**Nexus 7 Installer**
Because you do not have a Nexus 7, this isn't compatible, but you may find it interesting to learn more. This could also be an option for you, if you're willing to invest in buying a Nexus 7.

The Nexus 7 installer is not for commercial or normal use, and for developers only. It's very unstable and shouldn't be done by those who are not serious about developing with that software and hardware. Just like I said above, it's only for people really wishing to commit to this and people who won't cry about the countless bugs it has.
The Nexus 7 installer installs the ARM version of Ubuntu onto the device. That means it's the actual desktop OS, and isn't designed specifically for mobile devices.

If you wish to learn more about this you can use the sources below:

- [My answer about Ubuntu on Android](https://askubuntu.com/a/232887/78161)
- [Install instructions from the wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation)
- [Learn more from this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=W7Ypq78Hfss)

**Installing Ubuntu manually on your device**
The other option you have is installing the actual desktop OS onto your phone, which can be easy depending on what method you use. I have seen it in real life, so it does work. But doing this is completely your choice, and if you 'brick' your device or it breaks, you are not insured or protected. No-one will replace it or reimburse you, it's purely your own risk. [Zedomax - a YouTuber](http://www.youtube.com/user/zedomax) does many tutorial videos on how to install Ubuntu like this on many different devices.

If you wish to do this, you can view the links below:

- [How to root the Samsung Galaxy S3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJss1_dZZeY). This is a requirement to install Ubuntu on any device.
- [How to install Ubuntu on Android](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbunTRzEQCI)
- [Run Ubuntu on Mobile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0PNsnNe3E0)
- [Run Ubuntu Linux on Samsung Galaxy S3](http://www.addictivetips.com/android/run-ubuntu-linux-on-samsung-galaxy-s3/)
- [Samsung Galaxy S3 running Ubuntu](http://recombu.com/mobile/news/samsung-galaxy-s3-ubuntu_M18014.html)

[image: Ubuntu on android]

### Or you can wait for the new Ubuntu Phone OS!

Only a couple days ago there was an announcement from Mark Shuttleworth about the new Ubuntu Phone OS! Since not much has been revealed, and no-one really knows a whole heap about it - I can gives you links and links and more links. It's a pretty interesting read and watch.

- [Ubuntu Phone OS Unveiled](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/ubuntu-phone-os-unveiled-by-canonical)
- [Ubuntu for Phones](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone)
- ["Ubuntu Phone" by lockergnome on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iLw4xHBaB5w)
- [Ubuntu Phone hands-on demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXWnMTm7We8)
- [Ubuntu for Phones Trailer with Mark Shuttleworth](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoXpLUr5WB4)

[image: ubuntuphoneos]

Good luck!

Comment: Choose option one if you have the nexus 7, option two if you have balls, and option three if you have time.

Comment: Haha very true!