# Can I download Ubuntu for my Galaxy S lll Fido?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I dont like the Google and all other apps I have with my phone. I need a OS for my phone that I can surf the net, make calls, use a kind of OpenOffice app, have a contact list, etc. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can install Ubuntu on your galaxy S III. Here is a post that someone has already asked on the subject. [link here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235926/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s3)

Comment: Thank you Nate for your attention too. It was helpful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The information pertaining to your device are available on the page
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/i9300
Remember that Ubuntu Touch is still under development and we still have much work to do.
It is possible to find problems or the desired software is not yet available for installation or download

Comment: thank you for your attention Esigolo! :-) I am saving now to get an Ubuntu phone... I love photography and now there is this Huawei P9 with Leica lenses I hope soon I am able to make phone with good cameras work with Ubuntu. :-)