# Installing Ubuntu on Galaxy S3

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Galaxy S3, but I don't know how to do it.  I am looking for the best ROM for my phone and I've seen Ubuntu OS, but I can't get it to work.

I don't have Ubuntu install on my computer because it uses Windows applications. If ubuntu could run Windows apps, then I wound keep Ubuntu. How can I install Ubuntu on my phone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Ubuntu on the Samsung Galaxy S3?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235926/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s3)

Answer (score 2):

IMHO:

You may just need to wait for **AOSP** (http://source.android.com/) and **Ubuntu Touch** (based on AOSP) to support the Samsung *Galaxy S3* (i9300).

I would certainly like Ubuntu Touch on my *Galaxy S3 Mini* (i8190).

---

Real support is only for the (older) Galaxy-Nexus (maguro) and Nexus-4 (mako) smartphones, and the Nexus-7 (grouper) and Nexus-10 (manta) tablet. It is NOT there yet even for the newer: Nexus-5, Nexus-7 gen2 (aka '2013') or Nexus-10 gen2 (soon to be released).