# how to install Ubuntu Phone OS on my samsung galaxy s3?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, system-installation, ubuntu-for-android

Is there an guide or way to install the Ubuntu phone OS on other devices and is it safe?

I saw [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235926/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-the-samsung-galaxy-s3) but they are saying that is not stable yet. I'm asking about  "Ubuntu Phone OS"  and I need an installation Guide as well or preferably a step by step installation guide.

If any thing happens will I be able to but android on my phone again ?

thank you .

Comment: ..please visit these to see if they can help: [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android), [Instructions for flashing a phone or tablet device with Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)

Comment: I am a developer and would like to attempt this on my SGS3 I9300. All I want to know beforehand is whther the cellular radio has been sorted out by now? If so, please do post the details here, I am very well aware of the risks, but am more interested in putting ubuntu on with a changce of forcing myself to purchase a new phone :)

Comment: I am a developer and would like to attempt this on my SGS3 I9300. All I want to know beforehand is whther the cellular radio has been sorted out by now? If so, please do post the details here, I am very well aware of the risks, but am more interested in putting ubuntu on with a changce of forcing myself to purchase a new phone

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu version that xda installed on the phone is the desktop version and not the phone version. The phone specific OS currently only works with some moddels. It bricks most other moddels.

You will not be able to call anything with it if you install the desktop version on it.

That being said, No, there is no "safe" way of flashing any mobile machine. You can however reduce the risks if you know what you're doing and use safeguards like a nand backup.

there is always a slight chance of bricking your system. If that happens you will not be able to put android back on the phone and you'll be left with a very expensive paper weight.

If you're still interested in installing Ubuntu on your phone comment and I'll add the general guide of how to do it to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but the developer of the s3 project ended it while ago: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible as UBports community has build it for many devices and they also provide good documentation about how to port for other phones. Search for your device, and if you don't find your device, port Ubuntu Touch to your device.